# Transparent space between UITextField Input View and Accessary View

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode9, inputaccessoryview, inputview

I have tool bar as input accessary view and datepicker as input view for my date textfield.

[image]

Hotel booking label is behind that datepicker. When I touch on date textfield, It shows both input view and accessary view as I need. But what is the reason for that transparent space between input view and accessary view.

This issue started from Xcode 9.

Note :

When I copy date picker and toolbar from old projects then there is no transparent space. Its working as we expected. But When I drag date picker and toolbar from xcode 9 and above then there is a transparent space.

Please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, have you fixed this issue? I have faced issue like this on iOS 14.3. On my issue, the toolbar and datepicker are shown as expected as well, but when I open once mapbox's navigationViewController and back to any edit screen, the toolbar is hidden out of the top of screen and it just appears shortly when keyboard is dismissing. It looks there are large space - almost same height of screen between datepicker and toolbar. Please help me if you have any solution for this issue

Answer (score 1):

Also faced with this when drag from the object library toolbar and date picker to the storyboard.

Input view allows set your own view above keyboard. In portrait mode keyboard's height is 216. I've changed height of of the date picker from standard 162 to 216.

[image: picker's height]

Need think more about why when copy from old projects there are no space between accessory view and picker.